# When can I use the formula $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$?

Tags: probability

I have the pdf of $X$ and $Y$ to be:
$$
f_{X}(a)=f_{Y}(a)=ae^{-0.5a^{2}}I_{(0,\infty)}(a)
$$
It's also known that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution and are independent. I was asked to calculate the $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. In the solution they say that:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)\cdot f_Y(y)
$$
Which I understand why is true. But what conditions should be true so I could use this formula?

1. Should $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?
2. Should $X$ and $Y$ be independent?

In any case that the condition is not true, how should I calculate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ then?

Also, can I say the same thing for $F_{X,Y}=F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y)$?

Comment: What's your definition of [independence of two random vriables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_real_valued_random_variables)?

Comment: @TitoEliatron ok so I can use the formulas only if they are independent. How to calculate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ if I don't know if they are independent or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, amend an obvious typo in your post as the two densities are

$$a e^{-a^2/2}$$

and not as you wrote:

$$a e^{-e^2/2}$$

just FYK, this is a known density named [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)

Second, they explicitly said that $X\perp\!\!\!\!\!\!\perp Y$ and have the same distribution thus, using the definition of independence the joint density is simply

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=xye^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(x)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(y)$$

> Also, can I say the same thing for $F_{X,Y}=F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y)$?

Yes, you can!

Comment: What if they were not independent. How to calculate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ then?

Comment: @vesii : you can't! To do that you need some information about their dependence structure

Comment: @vesii:  try this classical example: $X$ and $Y$ are uniform in $(0;1)$ and it is known that $X<Y$. Calculate their joint density...